# Why is 857 larger than 1000 and 1001? Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following problem, my function accepts an array that contains 4 arrays, each element is a number. The functions must return the largest element of each array.

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  var largest = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    largest.push(arr[i].sort().pop());
  }
  console.log(largest);
  return largest;
}

largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

Results:

```
Array [ 5, 27, 39, 857 ]
```

Apparently it works, but when I tried with the last array [1000, 1001, 857, 1], in which 1000 and 1001 are larger than 857 I'm getting 857. Why does it happen?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

Answer (score 10, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Array values are sorted as strings. If you want to sort as numbers, use a custom comparitor function.

From the MDN docs:

```
var numberArray = [40, 1, 5, 200];

function compareNumbers(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}

console.log('numberArray:', numberArray.join());
console.log('Sorted without a compare function:', numberArray.sort());
console.log('Sorted with compareNumbers:', numberArray.sort(compareNumbers));
```

output:

> numberArray: 40,1,5,200
>   Sorted without a compare function: 1,200,40,5
>   Sorted with compareNumbers: 1,5,40,200

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `array#sort` method which compares values as strings rather than as numbers. A better solution is using `array.prototype.map` and `Math.max.apply`

```
function largestOfFour(array) {
    return array.map(function(arr) {
        return Math.max.apply(Math,arr);
    });
});

largestOfFour([[4,5,1,3],[13,27,18,26],[32,35,37,39],[1000,1001,857,1]]) 

=> [5,27,39,1001]
```

You can also pass in a function to `array#sort` and do something like this

```
array.sort(function(a,b) { return a - b })
```

The `pop()` function removes and returns the last element of an array. In this case, that will be 1001.

Comment: While a valid recommendation, this answer doesn't explain the effect for which the question seeks the cause.

Answer (score 2):

Bottom line: `8` is bigger than `1`.

Here's a concise article on the subject: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Try this:

```
arr.sort(function(a, b){return a-b}).pop();
```

Or just `Math.max()`

Comment: Please don't reference [*w3schools*](http://www.w3fools.com/). [*ECMAScript 2015*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.sort) is the definitive reference, [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) is helpful for examples.

Comment: Okay - thanks! I'm on mobile now. I'll fix it in a bit.

Comment: @RobG The W3Fools page no longer seems that critical of W3Schools: "W3Schools still has issues but they have at least worked on the primary concern developers had. For many beginners, W3Schools has structured tutorials and playgrounds that offer a decent learning experience."

Comment: @KyleStrand—I expect the authors of that page were approached by w3schools to tone down their criticism or face legal consequences. w3schools remains a commercial site that touts for business, they do not need free plugs and there are still significant technical errors in the site content. MDN is not free of errors, but at least anyone with an interest can fix them and improve the content.